# Can't login to phpmyadmin with accounts that were created by me

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I try to login to my phpmyadmin I get the following error, "#1045 - Access denied for user 'seconduser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" I already saw some articles about it and helped me to fix the root login but I want to have a second account...

**Some info:** I added it in the phpmyadmin interface and I tried the following. `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('*****') WHERE User='seconduser';` and after that `FLUSH PRIVILEGES; and EXIT`. And I'm still getting the errors...

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax..."

Comment: grant all privileges on \*.\* to 'root'@'localhost' with grant option; (Sorry, didn't know the \* was a special character, StackOverflow deletes it)

Comment: Not working... I get the same error "You have an error in your SQL syntax..."

Comment: Still can't login with the "secondaccount"

Comment: grant all privileges on \*.\* to 'secondaccount'@'localhost' with grant option; <-Replace secoundaccount with whatever account name

Comment: "Can't find any matching row in the user table" I tried with "%" and than worked (the sql code) and still can't login

Comment: This error seems to mean that the user does not exist. Can you show output of SELECT User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user; ?

Comment: Yes but the password field for it is empty...

Comment: I added a password to it with SQL code and still can't login